# Generating job and topology traces from history folder of multinode cluster using Rumen

Tags: hadoop

I have a single  node cluster from which i got logs and gave input TraceBuilder and it works.
I have grouped 5 node cluster under default rack and got logs. Here job and topology traces are generated properly.

I have set up 5 node cluster with each of them mapped to different racks.

I have hadoop-0.20.2 set up on my Eclipse Helios. So, i ran Tracebuilder using

Main Class: org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder
I ran some jobs on cluster and  used copy of /usr/local/hadoop/logs/history folder of master node as input to TraceBuilder.
Arguments: /home/arun/job.json  /home/arun/topology.json  /home/ubuntu/Documents/testlog

But i get

```
11/12/16 12:02:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
11/12/16 12:02:38 WARN rumen.TraceBuilder: TraceBuilder got an error while processing the [possibly virtual] file master_1324011575958_job_201112161029_0001_hduser_word+count within Path file:/home/ubuntu/Documents/testlog/master_1324011575958_job_201112161029_0001_hduser_word+count 
        java.lang.NullPointerException 
                at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.JobBuilder.processTaskAttemptFinishedEvent(JobBuilder.java:492) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.JobBuilder.process(JobBuilder.java:149) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder.processJobHistory(TraceBuilder.java:310) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder.run(TraceBuilder.java:264) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:69) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:83) 
                at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder.main(TraceBuilder.java:142) 
                .....................
```

It generates job trace json file but the fields like hostname and location are "null" in it and the topology trace json file doesn't have 5 node's info and is like this :

```
   { 
      "name" : "<root>", 
      "children" : [ ] 
    }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because none expected input file was found on input directory.
The input directory must to contain job files, for example: job_201205192032_0006_conf.xml. These files are stored inside the logs/history folder, but under some directories generated in accord with the job execution and  execution date